# Linux router: User friendly, web-based traffic monitor app

Tags: linux, linux-networking, web-applications

This is not a tech question but I hope someone can help me out.
I've been searching all over the web for an app like this, but I can't seem to find one:

1. Friendly user interface where a non-technical person can manage LAN computers.
2. Set individual download quotas. After that quota is reached, disable the internet connection for that specific host.

This app must not necessarily be free, but if it is, I wouldn't mind. :)

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on here. The functionality you seem to be looking for is something I associate with network management tools for hotels and WiFi hot-spots for customers. One potential search term is [Captive_portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) technology.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.ntop.org/ . It has comprehensive traffic stats and web interface easy to use by non-technical person.

The part with quotas is not that trivial, but ntop can certainly provide statistics based on which block can be applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am familiar with ntop, but unfortunatelly, it doesn't really do what I need...